# linear algebra: how to find two vectors so that spans $R^4$?

Tags: linear-algebra

How to solve this problem?

Given two vectors, $\vec{v}_1 = [1 ,1 ,0 ,-1]^T$ and $\vec{v}_2 = [0 ,0 ,1, 1]^T$, find two vectors $\vec{v}_3$ and $\vec{v}_4$ so that the set ܵ = {$\vec{v}_1$,  $\vec{v}_2$, $\vec{v}_3$,$\vec{v}_4$}
spans $R^4$.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Try guessing. Seriously, almost every vector is a fine a choice. You could try experimenting with some standard basis vectors, for example. Just make sure you check your answer at the end, because there are guesses that won't work.

Comment: There are an infinite number of answers and as Theo pointed out, in some sense almost any 'random' choice of vectors will work.

Comment: Can you figure out the span of the vectors you have? Well, then you better not add anything that is already in the span. Lather, rinse, repeat.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can set $v_3$ and $v_4$ to be span the orthogonal complement of the subspace spanned by $v_1$ and $v_2$.  To find a basis for $\text{Span}\{ v_3 , v_4 \}$, you want to solve the system:

$ \begin{bmatrix} v_1^T \\ v_2^T \end{bmatrix} x = 0 $

The solution is $x = t [-1, 1, 0, 0]^T + s [1, 0, -1, 1]^T $

Thus we can take $v_3 = [-1, 1, 0, 0]^T , v_4 = [1, 0, -1, 1]^T$